# how to extend the metadata in TYPO3 10.4.13

Tags: typo3, metadata, field, typo3-9.x, typo3-10.x

I am trying to add a description field under the page properties/metadata which was still present in the TYPO3 8.7.32 version.

I have also already tried in the setup with the following code:

```
page.meta.description.field = description

#page.meta.description.ifEmpty =
```

currently it looks like this
[image]

and should look like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to add a SEO description field, this field is already available in the SEO tab.

Nevertheless, if you want to add a new field in metadata, you have to :

Add the new field in : your_ext/ext_tables.sql

```
CREATE TABLE pages (
    new_field varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
);
```

Override the TCA  : create or update the file your_ext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/pages.php

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility;

call_user_func(static function () {
    // Define new TCA field
    $additionalFields = [
        'new_field' => [
            'exclude' => false,
            'l10n_mode' => 'prefixLangTitle',
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:pages.your_ext',
            'description' => 'LLL:EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:pages.your_ext.description',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 60,
                'max' => 255
            ]
        ]
    ];

    // Add the new TCA columns
    ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('pages', $additionalFields);
    
    // Add the field to the palette
    ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette('pages', 'metatags', 'new_field', 'after:keywords');
});
```

Then you have to update the DB with BE module Maintenance > Analyze Database Structure.

Flush all cache - because TCA are in cache.

And your new field will now be available.

Comment: And to use that new field with meta tag : page.meta.description.data = levelfield: -1, new_field, slide

Comment: Slide is technically ok. From a SEO view all pages should be different. So meta description should be different too.

Comment: Yes your're right Heinz, for those who don't know what slide mean, it means that if the field is empty for current page, Typo3 will look the parent pages until it finds non empty value for that field.